# Make clicking "manage" after saving a post auto-focus the list-selection dropdown

Tags: feature-request, saves, focus

This would be nice for quality-of-life for keyboard users. Save me some completely unnecessary key-presses would you? (Or explain to me why they're not completely unnecessary)

Also, while we're at it, why does the "save to" heading have `tabindex=0`? Why would I want to tab through it? Because of that, without this feature request (I.e. right now), you have to tab twice to reach the list selection menu instead of just once... Like- just-... why?

Comment: Good luck with that, auto focus isn't the strong side of SE. ;-(

Comment: How is that possible with a key press? Doesn't it require a mouse click (or the equivalent)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum how is _what_ possible? If you mean operating the dropdown, which is just a [`select` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select), you can use the spacebar or enter key to open the menu, arrow keys to navigate the options, and the enter key to choose an option. At least in Chrome. Not sure if that's a standard, or if it's up to the user agent. But I'm pretty sure any browser that's competent accessibility-wise will have _something_ for keyboard users.

Comment: The trouble is getting focus on "Manage" using the keyboard. It isn't possible by tabbing (at least not in Firefox). But I found a way: First get the focus on the link "For later" by typing "For l" (as much as makes it unique on the page) - this presumes [a particular configuration](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/06/29/setting-up-firefox-on-a-new-system/#keyboard-navigation) of Firefox. Then a single tab to change the focus to "Manage". This key sequence is coming to my macro keyboard very very soon!

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum yeah that bothers me too. That's a different problem- one step earlier than the step this question is about. I think the same ctrl+f method is required on Chrome as well. I'd write up a feature request but I'm personally not sure how best to tackle it. I'm not convinced that auto-focusing the manage button after saving something is a definitively good user experience. That's a great deal of movement of what is focused, and I might not necessarily want that focus change to happen.